# What is the difference between tournament selection and elitism in genetic algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

From the internet, I understood that **Elitism** *is the process where the best-performing chromosomes from the current generation will be passed on to the next generation* and **Tournament Selection** *is the process where the fittest chromosome from the current generation will be passed on to the next generation.*

But what I didn't understand is the difference between them. Both Elitism and Tournament Selection seem to mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is, that the Tournament selection works on a *subset* of the population. And from this *subset* the best individual is passed to the next generation. The typical subset (tournament) size is two or three. The Elite sector, on the other hand, works on the whole population.